# Adobe Creative SDK Android custom overlay images for Image Editor UI

Tags: android, overlay, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I implemented the Image Editor UI in my app.

There is a feature "Overlay" in it which lets the user to surround his image within a given overlay that is made by the SDK.

I want to add my own custom overlays to it, and block other overlays if possible.

I couldn't find any documentation about that.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Custom content is not a feature offered by the Creative SDK Image Editor. All content, including Overlays, is limited to what you see in the Image Editor.