# Adobecreativesdk: "Asking for customize more icon menus, localize menu text, adding frame and stickers by adobe team support

Tags: ios, swift, adobecreativesdk

Currently, I am working on the swift app which allow user to edit their own photos either by using camera or their own photo library. Adobe Creative sdk image editor is great; however, the possibility in order to customize the app interface is quite limited. I'd like to ask if there are solutions to solve these below points due to my business needed through any methods : 
- Customize every icons (menus/submenus) in image editors 
- Change text menu using other languages such Khmer language. For example, "Draw" => "គូរ"(Khmer language) etc. 
- Adding stickers and frames. 
By this [Adding Custom Frames and Stickers to Creative SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867230/adding-custom-frames-and-stickers-to-creative-sdk) it's not possible to do this by my own at this time. However, is it possible to ask adobe team to add those packages content either by purchasing license or additional charge something like this ?